# From pipe delimited to comma delimited?

Tags: perl, parsing, csv, split

I've got a working script that parses through a CSV file, scrubs the data and makes some changes before putting it back together.  The original file I was working with was comma-delimited.  But I just received all the actual files this will be run against and they are all pipe-delimited.  I need to do the same, then put them back together as comma-delimited files.

So to start, I have -

```
#!/usr/bin/perl/

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use Time::Piece;

my $filename = 'records.csv';

open my $FH, $filename
  or die "Could not read from $filename <$!>, program halting.";

# Read the header line.
chomp(my $line = <$FH>);
my @fields = split(/|/, $line);
print Dumper(@fields), $/;

my @data;
# Read the lines one by one.
while($line = <$FH>) {

    chomp($line);
```

...parse through my data, and then currently, I end with this to put the data back into the file -

```
# put the records back
    push @data, \@fields;
```

But how do I put the data back as comma-delimited?

Comment: I assume this is just a mis-copy, but `split(/|/, $line);` should be `split(/\|/, $line);`

Comment: *" I need to do the same, then put them back together as comma-delimited files"* No, you don't, you just need to split the data on pipes instead of commas and proceed as normal from there. Please don't try to recreate your "expected" input file from the real one first, as you will introduce a whole new layer of bugs

Comment: Thanks @ThisSuitIsBlackNot - it was actually me quickly throwing pipe in place of the comma that was originally there - didn't know I needed the escape!

Comment: @Borodin - I meant I don't need to change anything I'm doing within the script other than split it now on pipes and put it back together with commas.  The parsing and formatting within stays the same.

Comment: Since you were already (presumably) successfully splitting each line into fields, and you already know how to split on pipe characters, the rest of your code should be unchanged. The core of your question seems to be *"how do I put the data back as comma-delimited?"*  But that's independent of the original separator and you haven't shown any code that has anything to do with that. Please show the Perl code that you have tried and explain how it didn't work for you, and show some real-life input and output data

Comment: No @Borodin - I'm sorry if it's unclear.  ThisSuitIsBlackNot was pointing out that I needed the escape / for the | - which I did not know, not having worked with a pipe delimited file before.  What I don't know how to do is write the records back to the file with a comma delimiter since it was originally a pipe.

Comment: @BigRedEO Borodin is saying that you shouldn't convert your file to CSV. Just change your existing code to split on pipes instead of commas.

Comment: You will need to watch out for commas in the data fields. Pipe-delimited data allows a field to contain commas, but for comma-delimited output you will need to quote such a field.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot - but if I push it back to the file, won't it still be a pipe-delimited file?

Comment: @rici - my code in between scrubs all commas, single quotes, double quotes and backslashes.

Comment: @BigRedEO You're not `push`ing to a _file_; you're `push`ing to an _array_! What you're doing with that array is anybody's guess---you haven't shown us!

Comment: It sounds like the real problem is that you don't know how to join an array into a single string with separators between the elements. For that, we have [`join`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html)

Comment: @BigRedEO Push what back to what file? You have a pipe-delimited file containing your input data. Your end goal is presumably to parse the file to get the contents of each of the fields and do something with them. Based on your previous questions, it sounds like you've written a preprocessor to remove commas, quotes, etc. from a CSV, which is just an elaborate workaround to avoid using a proper CSV parser like Text::CSV. Now you're trying to convert your pipe-limited file to a CSV so your preprocessor can handle it, but this is just *another* hacky workaround, because *(continued)*

Comment: you could just modify your preprocessor to work on pipe-delimited files. Instead of all these hacky workarounds built upon workarounds, you should just download the source for Text::CSV and bundle it with your script. Text::CSV is just a Perl script and will eliminate the need for your preprocessor and your pre-preprocessor.

Comment: Please updater us on the status of this question. Is your problem solved?

Answer (score 2):

Do not parse CSV file using split. Use proper parser.

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use autodie;
use Text::CSV_XS;

my $csv_in = Text::CSV_XS->new( { binary => 1, sep_char => "|" } );
my $csv_out = Text::CSV_XS->new( { binary => 1, sep_char => ",", eol => $/ } );
while ( my $row = $csv_in->getline(*ARGV) ) {
    $csv_out->print( *STDOUT, $row );
}
```

If it is true you just need change pipe delimited to a comma delimited, insert `tr '|' ','` into your pipe.

Comment: My script was already working as is.  Just that now I have a pipe-delimited file and need it to be scrubbed and put back together as a comma-delimited file.  Text::CSV is not available to me nor will it be made available to me.  What I have works. I just need to now account for the pipes.

Answer (score 1):

A few things.  First, fix your shebang (the `#!` line) so it doesn't contain a trailing `/`.

Secondly, perl uses regular expressions for splitting, so you'll want to escape the pipe character when splitting:

```
my @fields = split(/\Q|\E/, $line);
```

Lastly, you can use [`join`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html) to join the elements of an array into a string.  This uses a string literal, not a regular expression.

```
my $output_line = join(',', @fields);
```

Comment: You have the variable $output_line to put the data back.  How would that work to write it back to the same file?  Or does it have to go to a different file name?

Comment: `split(/\Q|\E/, $line)` is usually written `split /\|/, $line`